# use python scipy.integrate.solve_ivp vectorization to solve for multiple initial conditions simultaneously

Tags: scipy, ode

I try to use  `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` with `vectorized=True` to solve a 2nd order system with $N$ initial states (x, y, xdot, ydot) at the same to avoid using a for loop. But the results I got is way off and very much different from the reasonable solutions using a regular for loop.

Can someone tell me if i am using the vectorize correctly? After passing into the solve_ivp arguments, I reshaped the flattened initial states (of size 4N) into a shape of (4, N). So, the first row is all the x's, 2nd row is all the y's, 3rd row is all the xdots and the 4th row is all the ydots.

Then I the ODE_func returns the flattened [[dxdt], [dydt], [ddxdtt], [ddydtt]] (an 1d array of size 4N). While defining the 2nd derivatives ddxdtt, i need to use some pre-computed arrays that I have defined ahead, so that every calculation can be simply performed within numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
```

```
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 7)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 7)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
a = 2
inside = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2) <= a
outside = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2) > a

# setting up backgroud fields
Ux = 2 * X ** 2 + 3 * Y
Ux[outside] = 5 * X[outside] - Y[outside]
dUxdx = 4 * X
dUxdx[outside] = 5
dUxdy = 3 * np.ones_like(Ux)
dUxdy[outside] = -1 
dUxdt = np.zeros_like(Ux)

Uy = -4 * Y + X ** 2
Uy[outside] = X[outside] + 2 * Y[outside]
dUydx = 2 * X
dUydx[outside] = 1
dUydy = -4 * np.ones_like(Uy)
dUydy[outside] = 2
dUydt = np.zeros_like(Uy)

grids = np.row_stack((X.flatten(), Y.flatten()))
IC = np.row_stack((X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), Ux.flatten(), Uy.flatten()))
input = IC.flatten()
```

```
def func_vec(t, Z):
    
    Z = np.reshape(Z, (4, -1))

    dZdt = np.zeros_like(Z)
    dZdt[0, :] = Z[2, :]
    dZdt[1, :] = Z[3, :]
    dZdt[2, :] = Ux.flatten() * dUxdx.flatten() + Uy.flatten() * dUxdy.flatten()
    dZdt[3, :] = Ux.flatten() * dUydx.flatten() + Uy.flatten() * dUydy.flatten()

    out = dZdt.flatten()
    return out
```

```
sol_vec = solve_ivp(func_vec, [0, 10], input, 'RK45', np.linspace(0, 10, 10), vectorized=True)
sol_vec_state = sol_vec.y.reshape((4, -1, len(sol_vec.t)))
sol_vec_x = sol_vec_state[0, :, :].reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], len(sol_vec.t)))
sol_vec_y = sol_vec_state[1, :, :].reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], len(sol_vec.t)))
```

Comment: that's not what `vectorize` is for.  Read the docs more carefully.  It's about how your function is written.

Comment: thanks, i see now. But in any case, is there a method to improve the computation time when i have many initial states to integrate?

Comment: computation time is basically a functiin of how many times (steps) it takes and the evaluation time of your function.  The idea behind the vectorize parameter is to speed up the jacobian evaluation. As for multiple initial states, is optimal to run each on its own (number of steps), or expand you function to handle all runs together (even if the aren't coupled).  Anyways you're not the first to ask this.